# Trying to scrape data out of <div> elements with specific class name

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from the following sports statistics page: https://www.sofascore.com/tournament/football/france/ligue-1/34#42273 (Season 22/23)

The table I want to scrape is the "Standings" table using the `rvest` package. I have come so far that I know that I can read out the contained HTML text based on certain class names. Now I would like to do exactly that on an example site about the french "Ligue 1" on sofascore.com. The `<div>` class name of the html elements I want to scrape is "sc-hLBbgP sc-eDvSVe gjJmZQ fRddxb sc-526d246a-0 evdGB" (Screenshot below) and I have tried to specify it in the `html_elements()` function but it just won't work properly.

[image]

My current code:

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "https://www.sofascore.com/tournament/football/france/ligue-1/34#42273"
HTML <- read_html(URL)

HTML %>%
html_elements("div") %>%
html_elements(".sc-hLBbgP sc-eDvSVe gjJmZQ fRddxb sc-526d246a-0 evdGB")
```

**The result:**

> {xml_nodeset (0)}

Until the `<div>` part of the code the HTML code can still be read out but as soon as the class name is entered it ends up in an empty vector. What am I doing wrong that the `html_elements()` function won't get it hands on the text information in this `<div>` node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that if your activity triggers any anti-scraping measures, they will just ban your IP:
[image: cloudflare IP ban]

---

Extending Adam's answer, this is how collecting and parsing "Standings" table data might look like:

```r
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

# we'll first extract season id(s) from the page source 
# (also matches the hash in url, #42273)
url_ <- "https://www.sofascore.com/tournament/football/france/ligue-1/34#42273"
read_html(url_) %>% 
  html_element("script#__NEXT_DATA__") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  fromJSON() %>% 
  pluck("props", "pageProps", "seasons") %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  print(n = 3)
#> # A tibble: 27 × 5
#>   name          year  editor    id seasonCoverageInfo
#>   <chr>         <chr> <lgl>  <int> <df[,0]>          
#> 1 Ligue 1 23/24 23/24 FALSE  52571                   
#> 2 Ligue 1 22/23 22/23 FALSE  42273                   
#> 3 Ligue 1 21/22 21/22 FALSE  37167                   
#> # ℹ 24 more rows

# we can then use those values to construct an API call that was used to fill Standings table:
season_id <- "42273"
api_call <- paste0("https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/unique-tournament/34/season/", season_id, "/standings/total")

# fetch / parse JSON / table data from nested list / re-shape/re-structure / drop some columns:
fromJSON(api_call, simplifyVector = FALSE) %>% 
  pluck("standings", 1, "rows") %>% 
  tibble(rows = . ) %>% 
  unnest_wider(rows) %>% 
  hoist(team, name = "name", sname = "shortName") %>% 
  select(!where(is.list), -descriptions, -id)
```

Result:

```r
#> # A tibble: 20 × 10
#>    name        sname position matches  wins scoresFor scoresAgainst losses draws
#>    <chr>       <chr>    <int>   <int> <int>     <int>         <int>  <int> <int>
#>  1 Paris Sain… PSG          1      38    27        89            40      7     4
#>  2 Lens        Lens         2      38    25        68            29      4     9
#>  3 Olympique … Mars…        3      38    22        67            40      9     7
#>  4 Stade Renn… Renn…        4      38    21        69            39     12     5
#>  5 Lille       Lille        5      38    19        65            44      9    10
#>  6 AS Monaco   AS M…        6      38    19        70            58     11     8
#>  7 Olympique … Lyon         7      38    18        65            47     12     8
#>  8 Clermont F… Cler…        8      38    17        45            49     13     8
#>  9 Nice        Nice         9      38    15        48            37     10    13
#> 10 Lorient     Lori…       10      38    15        52            53     13    10
#> 11 Stade de R… Reims       11      38    12        45            45     11    15
#> 12 Montpellier Mont…       12      38    15        65            62     18     5
#> 13 Toulouse    Toul…       13      38    13        51            57     16     9
#> 14 Stade Bres… Brest       14      38    11        44            54     16    11
#> 15 Strasbourg  Stra…       15      38     9        51            59     16    13
#> 16 Nantes      Nant…       16      38     7        37            55     16    15
#> 17 Auxerre     Auxe…       17      38     8        35            63     19    11
#> 18 Ajaccio     Ajac…       18      38     7        23            74     26     5
#> 19 Troyes      Troy…       19      38     4        45            81     22    12
#> 20 Angers      Ange…       20      38     4        33            81     28     6
#> # ℹ 1 more variable: points <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: margusl, your solution is a godsend. It works perfectly in right the way I need it.

Answer (score 2):

Using your code I then ran a bit more to see what information I could find.

```
rvest::html_text(HTML) %>% writeClipboard()
```

If you copy this into a text editor you will find that your html elements do not exist. There are two ways you can try to deal with this.

1. You can use a session `?rvest::session` with a user agent `?user_agent` to tell rvest to act like Chrome (search for how to use a user agent and you can find instructions).
2. You can skip all that and notice that the data is pulled from an API and you can direction connect to the API. Under the network tab of the inspector you can see all of the network calls made when loading the page. Several of them are API calls with the data you need. You can see the URL for one of the API calls in the Headers tab is https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/unique-tournament/34/season/42273/standings/total which will give you the data for that table in JSON without loading any HTML at all. You can look through this tab until you find the JSON with all the data you need.

[image]

Comment: Regarding the 1st mentioned method, I'm afraid using sessions and changing user agent will not automagically inteoduce javascript evaluation for rvest nor force it to make relevant API requests.

Comment: Adam, you have shown me that the right approach for my issue was a completely different one than I thought. With your explanations I have understood that information can be stored outside the HTML text itself and that text scraping methods can fail miserably this way. For this valuable input I am thankful.

I have given margusl the solution check mark but your input was also valuable for giving me a fundamental understanding of my problem.